# Set Null DateTime in InsertQuery

Tags: datetime, null

I have a dataset and it has a InsertQuery(String Name,String Surname,DateTime BDate)

Now I can wirte code like this,

**_t.InsertQuer("Alper","AYDIN", null);**

it can record data OK,

But I want to do like this,

**_t.InsertQuery("Alper","AYDIN", dtBDate.IsEmpty==true?null:dtBDate.Value);**

But when I Depoly it is give error like this;

Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '' and 'System.DateTime'

How Can I set null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional operator needs to be able to return a single data type. Cast the null value to the null version of the other type:

```
_t.InsertQuery("Alper","AYDIN", dtBDate.IsEmpty?(DateTime?)null:dtBDate.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
_t.InsertQuery("Alper","AYDIN", dtBDate);
```

where `dtBDate` is `Nullable<DateTime>`.

Also notice that you cannot pass `null` if the `InsertQuery` method takes `DateTime` instead of `Nullable<DateTime>` as last parameter.